# Can's show toast when click - Android app

Tags: java, android

I have a problem with listview, I can't click on item listview, I find problem in `Checkbox` it understand checkbox.setoncheckedchangeLisnter when Click, how can fix it?

fullcode: https://github.com/QuDaMyker/listView

`Adapter.java`
[Adapter](https://i.stack.imgur.com/i3HYR.png)

```java
package com.example.testlistview;

import android.content.Context;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.CheckBox;
import android.widget.TextView;

import androidx.annotation.NonNull;
import androidx.annotation.Nullable;

import java.util.List;

public class Adapter extends ArrayAdapter<TodoClass> {
    private Context context;
    private List<TodoClass> list;

    public Adapter(@NonNull Context context, int resource, @NonNull List<TodoClass> objects) {
        super(context, resource, objects);
        this.context = context;
        this.list = objects;
    }

    @NonNull
    @Override
    public View getView(int position, @Nullable View convertView, @NonNull ViewGroup parent) {
        convertView = LayoutInflater.from(context.getApplicationContext()).inflate(R.layout.item_listview, parent, false);

        TextView stt = convertView.findViewById(R.id.stt);
        stt.setText(String.valueOf(position));

        TextView title = convertView.findViewById(R.id.title);
        title.setText(list.get(position).getTitle());

        TextView date = convertView.findViewById(R.id.date);
        date.setText(list.get(position).getDate());

        CheckBox checkBox = convertView.findViewById(R.id.checkBox);
        checkBox.setChecked(list.get(position).getChecked());

        return convertView;
    }
}
```

`MainActivity`
[MainActivity](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SoSQC.png)

```java
package com.example.testlistview;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.AdapterView;
import android.widget.CheckBox;
import android.widget.ListView;
import android.widget.Toast;

import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    private ListView listView;
    private List<TodoClass> list;
    private Adapter adapter;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        listView = findViewById(R.id.listView);
        list = new ArrayList<>();
        list.add(new TodoClass("1", "1", "04/24/2003", false));
        list.add(new TodoClass("2", "1", "04/24/2003", false));
        list.add(new TodoClass("3", "1", "04/24/2003", false));
        list.add(new TodoClass("4", "1", "04/24/2003", false));
        list.add(new TodoClass("5", "1", "04/24/2003", false));
        list.add(new TodoClass("6", "1", "04/24/2003", false));
        list.add(new TodoClass("7", "1", "04/24/2003", false));
        list.add(new TodoClass("8", "1", "04/24/2003", false));
        list.add(new TodoClass("8", "1", "04/24/2003", false));



        adapter = new Adapter(MainActivity.this, R.layout.item_listview, list);
        listView.setAdapter(adapter);

        listView.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Click", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                CheckBox checkBox = view.findViewById(R.id.checkBox);

                list.get(position).setChecked(!list.get(position).getChecked());
                checkBox.setChecked(list.get(position).getChecked());
            }
        });



    }
}
```

`TodoClass`
[TodoClass](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5OqIm.png)

```java
package com.example.testlistview;

public class TodoClass {
    private String Title;
    private String Desc;
    private String Date;
    private Boolean Checked;

    public TodoClass(String title, String desc, String date, Boolean checked) {
        Title = title;
        Desc = desc;
        Date = date;
        Checked = checked;
    }

    public String getTitle() {
        return Title;
    }

    public void setTitle(String title) {
        Title = title;
    }

    public String getDesc() {
        return Desc;
    }

    public void setDesc(String desc) {
        Desc = desc;
    }

    public String getDate() {
        return Date;
    }

    public void setDate(String date) {
        Date = date;
    }

    public Boolean getChecked() {
        return Checked;
    }

    public void setChecked(Boolean checked) {
        Checked = checked;
    }
}
```

Thanks for your help, i stuck in this bug so long time :((((

not working Toast
Android don't show error

Comment: You should add Logs or more details.

Comment: Try completely uninstalling and reinstalling the app. Or rewrite the whole MainActivity.class from scratch

Answer (score 0):

Change getApplicationContext() to **MainActivity.this** in your Toast statement of your MainActivity->listView.setOnItemClickListener method. Then the Toast message will show up. I tried it and it worked fine. Here is my tested code.

```
    ListView lv = findViewById(R.id.lstv);
    List<String> arr = new ArrayList<>();
    arr.add("aa");
    arr.add("bb");
    arr.add("cc");
    arr.add("dd");
    arr.add("ee");
    ListAdapter adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, androidx.appcompat.R.layout.support_simple_spinner_dropdown_item, arr);
    lv.setAdapter(adapter);

    lv.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
            Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Hello", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

        }
    });
```

Comment: hmmm, it still not working, let's see full code: https://github.com/QuDaMyker/listView, please help me review this code, thanks.

Comment: I edited my answer. I have used ListAdapter instead of Adapter. Try out this change.

Comment: I find issue in Checkbox, when i use checkbox, i can't use onClickItemListener, if i remove checkbox, onClickItemListerner working good, now i think why haveing this issue